# Define JSDoc type using a variable [WebStorm-friendly]

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

In the following code I would like to define a shape of `ApplicationSettings` type using `testSettings` variable, so that inside `useSettings` function IDE would know which properties are accessible on the `settings` object:

```
/** @typedef ApplicationSettings */
var testSettings = {
    apiService: {},
    configuration: {}
};

/**
 * @param {ApplicationSettings} settings
 */
function useSettings(settings) {
    console.log(settings.apiService); // apiService is not recognized here
    console.log(settings.configuration); // same for configuration
}
```

Unfortunately, seems that `@typedef` is not a valid annotation in that case. Is it possible to tell WebStorm how `ApplicationSettings` type should look like without explicitly specifying all of its properties in JSDoc?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need @typedef here? the following syntax works:

```
var testSettings = {
    apiService: {},
    configuration: {}
};

/**
 * @param {testSettings} settings
 */
function useSettings(settings) {
    console.log(settings.apiService); 
    console.log(settings.configuration);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but what if the settings object and the function are in different modules? I don't really want the function annotation to depend on the exact name of the `testSettings` variable. It can easily be renamed tomorrow, type annotations seem to be more "permanent" from the developer's points of view.